# How does iTunes track/identify a song in its music library?

Tags: itunes

This may not sound like a programming issue, but I'm trying to implement similar rating feature like iTunes does, and I'm curious about how iTunes track a song like this:

After I rate a song in iTunes, even though I change the meta tags(artist/title/album), it can match the song and show the rating, and even I move the file to another folder or change the filename, the rating is still there, I dig a little bit and found in 'iTunes Music Library.xml', there's a 'persistent Id' for each song, I think the 'persistent Id' is the key, but I'm still confused about how iTunes matches the 'persistent Id' with a song even though user can change the filename/meta tag of the audio file.

any idea?